# Comparing (diff) different files with same names in lots of directories and subdirectories

Tags: bash, compare, diff, subdirectory

I have the following directory structure in `LINUX`

[image]

In every single folder (except home), there's a file called `myfile.xml`

I want to compare (preferably using `diff`) all of the `myfile.xml` files. So, I want the code to automatically go in all subdirectories (as deep as it goes) and look for `myfile.xml` and compare them. It can also compare all of the files to 1 of them. I cannot find how to do that.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick one of the `xml` files, say it's `home/hello/myfile.xml`. Then run a `find` (assuming you are in the folder just above `home`):

```
find home -name "myfile.xml" -print -exec diff home/hello/myfile.xml {} \;
```

This will compare `home/hello/myfile.xml` with each of the other ones, and precede each diff output with the path name of the file being compared.

If you want a way to programmatically get the first file, you could do something like this:

```
basexml=$(find home -name "myfile.xml" | head -1)
find home -name "myfile.xml" -print -exec diff $basexml {} \;
```

If you want a message indicating a difference before the difference output (and only if there's a difference), then you could create a small shell script as follows:

```
dout=$(diff $1 $2)

if [ ! "$?" = "0" ]; then
    echo "${1##*/} is different on ${1%/*} and ${2%/*}"
    echo $dout
fi
```

I'm not sure what the limit is on how much a shell variable can hold, so you may need a temp file:

```
diff $1 $2 > /tmp/$0$$

if [ ! "$?" = "0" ]; then
    echo "${1##*/} is different on ${1%/*} and ${2%/*}"
    cat /tmp/$0$$
fi

rm -f /tmp/$0$$
```

Let's say this script is called `sdiff.sh`, then your `find` would be:

```
find home -name "myfile.xml" -exec sh sdiff.sh $basexml {} \;
```

In the script, I named the temp file as `$0$$` which is the script's name followed by its process ID. So the name will appear as `/tmp/sdiff.shXXXXX` where `XXXXX` is the process ID. In this case, I probably didn't have to be that "fancy" (we could have just called it `$0.tmp` or something).

Comment: +1 Seems to be working. I'll make sure and test it then i'll accept. thank you

Comment: Is it possible to `echo` something every time it finds a difference?
For example `"myfile.xml" is different on /home/hello/ and /home/hello/1.0/` Then display the difference

Comment: Yes it is possible with `find` but it won't know there's a difference until after the `diff` is executed, so such a phrase would be echoed after the `diff` occurs. Do you want to omit the `diff` output and just indicate that there is a difference?

Comment: no no I want to say there is a difference then display the difference. I thought of doing the following.
`me=$(find home -name "myfile.xml" -print -exec diff home/hello/myfile.xml {} \;)`
Then i have access with the array `me` right?
`echo "${me[0]}"`

Comment: In that case, I would make a small shell script to do the `diff` and save the result, echo a string, then echo the `diff` output. If you just try to do it through `find`, `diff`, and `echo`, `find` won't know whether `diff` succeeded or failed until it executes. So it wouldn't know to output anything else on a difference until the difference output occurred.

Comment: Wow
it did the job. Awesome. I have no idea what the script, the `1##*/`, `1%/*` and `tmp/$0$$` are nor what they're doing but it did the job

Comment: @Martin, `${1##*/}` is a short way of getting `basename $1`, `${1%/*}` is a short way of getting `dirname $1`, and `/tmp/$0$$` is a temp file name made from `$0` (which is the script name) concatenated with `$$` which is the current process number.

Comment: What if i wanted to add some `grep` and `awk` and/or `sed` to the diff? Where would I do that? I'm trying to do that right now

Comment: You could include it in between the `diff` command and the `> /tmp/$0$$`. So, for example, `diff $1 $2 | sed ... > /tmp/$0$$`.